# Yii: Removing unnecessary URL parameters

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem:
I have programed my application with SEO friendly URLs, according to the manual in the following way:

http://example.com/page/page-slug

with the following URLManager rules:

```
'page/<slug:.*?>/<page:.*?>'=>'page/view',
'page/<slug:.*?>/'=>'page/view',
```

Everything works fine, but when the link is shared (i don't know actually where), some additionar parameters are added in a freakish way:

http://example.com/page/page-slug**&locale=en_us&mobile=true&numposts=5**

and when that happens, the page throws an error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

traced to a private function inside my controller that doesn't has anything to do with this.

So my question goes to:

How can I sanitize the request url in the beforeAction? Is there any way?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do would be improve the rules so that they only accept expected values. Currently you're letting almost anything though. Something along the lines of:

```
'page/<slug:\w+>/<page:[a-z\-]+>'=>'page/view',
'page/<slug:\w+>/'=>'page/view',
```

By doing so you ensure that...

```
http://example.com/page/page-slug&locale=en_us&mobile=true&numposts=5
```

...results in a 404 as the URL doesn't match your rules.

However that URL is malformed anyway, as the first ampersand should be a question mark. So if you are expecting bad URLs, you can look out for them. This is a very rough bit of regex, but you get the idea:

```
'page/<slug:\w+>/<page:[a-z\-]+>&<rubbish:.*>'=>'page/viewWithBadUrls',
```

And in your actionViewWithBadUrls() controller method you'd get:

```
print_r($_GET); // Array ( [slug] => page [page] => page-slug [rubbish] => locale=en_us&mobile=true&numposts=5 )
```

Which you could use, or clean up the URL and 301 to the correct place